# DFWP slow - EnsureListItemsData

Tags: data-form-web-part

I have a webpart page that has a single Data Form Webpart that is very slow.  Appears from Developer Dashboard that the webpart is causing several (long executing) EnsureListItemsData calls. I am assuming that I have some DB issue - but am not sure how to debug further - any help is appreciated!  This site was a SP2007 site that was migrated to SP2010.  Developer Dashboard info:

> BeginRequestHandler (0.04 ms)
>   ◦PostAuthenticateRequestHandler (0.06 ms)
>   ◦PostResolveRequestCacheHandler (16.91 ms)
>   ◾GetWebPartPageContent (15.75 ms)
>   ◾GetFileAndMetaInfo (15.48 ms)
>   ◦GetWebPartPageContent (23.41 ms)
>   ◾GetFileAndMetaInfo (23.25 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData (48.83 ms)
>   ◦PortalSiteMapDataSource: Determining Starting Node (0.02 ms)
>   ◦PortalSiteMapDataSource: Determining Starting Node#1 (0.01 ms)
>   ◦Add WebParts (18.48 ms)
>   ◾New Service Ticket (0.16 ms)
>   ◾Newly Assigned Service Tickets (18.06 ms)
>   ◦ToolBarMenuButton.CreateChildControls for SiteActions (0.56 ms)
>   ◦ToolBarMenuButton.CreateChildControls for PersonalActions (0.09 ms)
>   ◦SearchBoxEx.OnLoad (0.33 ms)
>   ◾SearchBoxEx.HandleContextualScoping (0.14 ms)
>   ◾SearchBoxEx.GetSpWeb (0.01 ms)
>   ◦Activate web part connections (0.03 ms)
>   ◦DataBinding DataFormWebPart (Newly Assigned Service Tickets) (41.40 ms)
>   ◾EnsureListItemsData (31.89 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#1 (1523.61 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#2 (1214.19 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#3 (1134.38 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#4 (1251.88 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#5 (1199.81 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#6 (1183.24 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#7 (1225.59 ms)
>   ◦EnsureListItemsData#8 (1224.11 ms)
>   ◦PortalSiteMapNode: Populating navigation children for web: /APPS/SD (18.91 ms)
>   ◦PortalSiteMapNode: Populating navigation children for web: /APPS/SD#1 (1.95 ms)
>   ◦Render Ribbon. (2.69 ms)
>   ◦Render WebPart Zone Left (0.58 ms)
>   ◾Render WebPart New Service Ticket (0.10 ms)
>   ◾Render WebPart Newly Assigned Service Tickets (0.33 ms)
>
> Database Queries from Developer Dashboard:
>   proc_FetchDocForHttpGet 15.01 ms  
>   proc_FetchDocForHttpGet 11.75 ms 
>  
>   SELECT t1.[TimeCreated] 45.46 ms 
>  
>   proc_GetCurrent 2.82 ms  
>   proc_GetTpWebMetaDataAndListMetaData 6.08 ms  
>   proc_SecRefreshToken 43.42 ms  
>   proc_GetTpWebMetaDataAndListMetaData 6.13 ms  
>   proc_SecRefreshToken 3.63 ms  
>   proc_GetChanges 3.28 ms  
>   proc_GetListWebParts 12.67 ms  
>   proc_GetListMetaDataAndEventReceivers 6.27 ms  
>   DECLARE @DocParentIdForRF 12.86 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1520.41 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1210.92 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1129.92 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1247.78 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1196.30 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1178.67 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1220.98 ms  
>   SELECT t23.[ntext4], 1219.56 ms  
>   proc_GetTpWebMetaDataAndListMetaData 7.01 ms 
>  
>   proc_SecRefreshToken 3.77 ms  
>   proc_GetWebNavStruct 6.05 ms